# Firebird table index deactivated after backup/restore

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

After a backup/restore of my database in Firebird, I found out that the index of one of my tables got deactivated.  It was activated before the backup. I did the backup/restore using FlameRobin with the default settings.  I want to point out that the indices of the other tables where correctly activated, only the one of the biggest table got deactivated.

Could it be that the index is automatically deactivate during the backup/restore if the table is above a certain size? Is is possible to be sure that this issue doesn't happen again by using some options during the backup/restore?

Comment: Indexes are only activated *after* the data is restored. If one of the indexes is not active, then it means that your backup did not complete successfully, and possibly other things haven't been activated either. Perform a restore of the original backup with the -verify option (which produces verbose output, it doesn't actually verify things) and check the output (and include it, specifically errors, here in your question).

Comment: As an aside, Firebird 2.1 went out of support in December 2014 with the release of Firebird 2.1.7. Do yourself and your customers a favour and work on upgrading to a supported version. Several security issues have been fixed in later versions, and Firebird 3.0 and higher provide more secure authentication options than earlier versions.

Comment: You may also want to consider asking on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) instead of here, because troubleshooting questions (which require back and forth for getting more information) are not really suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for your answers, I will try to redo the backup and restore, but I did not saw any error last time I did it.
For the firebird version I know it has to be updated but this is not up to me.
I will have a look with the firebird-support as well.

Comment: Doing a new backup after the damage is already done will likely not reproduce the issue, because likely the thing that caused the problem was not restored, so subsequent backups will not contain it anymore. You need the original backup.

Comment: Yes I still have the original backup, I will use this one, sorry if I was not clear

Comment: Make sure to use -V switch during restore.

Comment: @user13964273 I already mentioned that in my first comment (using the full option name, `-verify`)